# Rygel showing deleted default folders

Tags: configuration, dlna, rygel

I have Rygel installed and configured on my home server, and have nothing in the default /user/Music;Videos;Pictures folders, so I would like to stop Rygel from searching and displaying them. I've deleted the default uris and set Tracker to enabled=false in both /etc/rygel.conf and ~/.config/rygel.conf, but my DLNA devices still show Files & Folders, Music, Videos, and Pictures. Is there anything else I can try so that only Files & Folders shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~/.config/rygel.conf` in the MediaExport section add a line for virtual-folders and restart:

```
[MediaExport]
virtual-folders=false
```

Comment: Have the same problem, tried the same solution, but doesn't work here. Despite of virtual-folders=false in the [MediaExport] and restart, they all pop up.
It is worse here, since all clients (Android, W10) see two identically named instances, one showing the media defined in uris; and one showing the empty video, musics and pictures folders.

Comment: Okay, solution is here. Wanted to write it to upstream people, but seems a dead project. Whatever.
Here, in 2023, man rygel.conf rightly states: "If ... Tracker as well as MediaExport are enabled, MediaExport will disable itself in favour of the Tracker plugin". However, by default there is a [Tracker] and a [Tracker3] section. This behaviour doesn't apply to [Tracker3], so in there one needs to set "enabled=false" in [Tracker3] section.